# inconsistency between "docker system df" and Docker Desktop on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

```
#docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          222       0         42.87GB   42.87GB (100%)
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   10        0         77.68MB   77.68MB (100%)
Build Cache     946       0         7.982GB   7.982GB
```

From the `docker system df` command, it seems my docker disk is running out of space. But Docker desktop shows:
[image]

So I am confused which one should be the right one to indicate docker space usage?

Comment: what docker-desktop version are you using? just to confirm cause I'm using docker-desktop for windows, is the image you've added to the thread from the docker-desktop dashboard? also, please add your storage usage for the Device holding the docker desktop data (probably some internal disk)

Comment: Why do you say the `docker system df` command shows you are running out of space?

Comment: Really docker system df should show something more like what df in linux/unix shows, which would be more like what is shown in the docker desktop. It's pretty bad that there's no command line command to find disk space usage for volumes in docker desktop.

Comment: @BMitch I guess I had a wrong interpretation of RECLAIMABLE but still the output is still pretty confusing and not explicit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a mac/windows, then it means that behind the scenes you're running a VM running linux. That disk size then corresponds to the VM disk size containing the Linux distro, rather than just the docker stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `RECLAIMABLE` column is basically the size and percentage of the resources that aren't in use, there is no container using these images/volumes. In your case, 100% of the images and volumes are in "Idle" so you can remove them if you want, there are some good ways to remove it like [docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) and [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/).

The image that you sent has what you are looking for.

Comment: Then what is the command corresponding to the `Disk image size` in the picture?

Comment: sorry, I don't know. I can check it later @derek.